# Unable to locate element: //input[@name="session[username_or_email]"] using python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am a beginner when it comes to selenium and web scraping as a whole, and today I was trying to follow a tutorial on selenium where they use the command:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com/home")
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="session[username_or_email]"]')
```

to find the input tag in the html of the twitter log-in page:
[image: snippet from the html of twitter login-page]

but when i try to run the code it shows me this:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@name="session[username_or_email]"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that means the element u r looking for is not exist, please share the link of the website u want to scarp so I can help you better?

Comment: I've looked at the twitter login page, and using Firefox dev tools verified that your xpath should find the element.  Can you share the code leading up to that statement?

Comment: Could you paste your whole code? The finding this element with xpath works for me when I'm on twitter login page.
Maybe you are not on the login page?

Comment: @Richard, thanks for trying to help I edited the post so the code now appears in full. Other than that I found add if I had a time.sleep(5) before defining the username then it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Providing some wait statement to find the element. There is 3 ways to provide the wait -

1. Using sleep()

   ```
    time.sleep(20)
    username = 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="session[username_or_email]"]')
   ```
2. Explicit wait

   ```
   wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
   username = wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(By.xpath( 
   "//input[@name='session[username_or_email]']")))
   ```
3. Implicit Wait

   ```
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    username = 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="session[username_or_email]"]')
   ```